# New High Quality Posts review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I want to propose a new review queue called: "High Quality Posts" review queue.

### What kind of posts should be in this queue?

The High Quality Posts review queue should be the exact opposite from Low Quality Posts. Only posts with a high quality should go and be in this queue.

The High Quality Posts review queue should bring attention to posts which are very unknown, not many views and not many votes.

<sub>Just as one example for such a post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/3933332</sub>

### Who can access this queue?

Everyone who earned the ["Access Review Queues"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege can access this queue. And as in all other review queues you can do 20 reviews per day.

### How does a post get into this queue?

If you earned a [gold-badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) for a specific tag, you can send a limited amount of posts per day into this queue. The amount of posts you can send into this queue doesn't increase in any way, nor does  it when you have multile gold-badges for tags.

### How does a post get out of this queue?

After a specific time the post automatically goes out of the queue. Or if 3 users pressed the <kbd>**Low Quality**</kbd> button for a post it automatically goes out of the queue.

(Also if multiple posts, which got send into the queue by one user, gets voted out of the queue, that user gets a warning or a ban for some time, where he can't send any posts into this queue)

### What actions can I make in this queue?

- <kbd>**Low Quality**</kbd> (Bad and low quality post, after 3x of this actions the post automatically goes out of the queue)
- <kbd>**Look OK**</kbd> (Enough quality to stay in the queue, but you don't want to up vote)
- <kbd>**High Quality**</kbd> (up vote)

### Why do we need this queue?

- High quality posts deserve much more attention
- Brings attention to high quality post which are unknown, don't have many views and don't have many votes
- Encourage users more to post high quality posts and put effort into their posts
- Gives motivation and something back to the users who put some real effort and time into their posts
- (Makes it easier to find good/high quality questions which maybe haven't an answer yet)

Comment: Check out the "stats" tab under [the 10K tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools)

Comment: @Shog9 Exactly, you find posts with many views or votes, but not old posts or posts with almost no views or votes which still have a very high quality. But these posts maybe are very good to use as duplicate or so. I think this would help a little to even better identify the quality of a post and give something back to those who really put some real effort into their posts.

Comment: If they're good enough to get into this high queue in the first place - what will upvoting it even more accomplish here?

Comment: @Shog9 Completely updated my question to make it clear. (Should I post it as new question, since I completely rewrote the question?)

Comment: @Rob updated my question to show exactly for what we need this queue.

Comment: I feel like VLQ are more of a problem then "unseen HQ", so creating a new queue that would just take time away from the low quality ones might not be needed...

Comment: @Patrice Yes that's true. High quality posts don't need any or not much time/actions. But don't you think too, that a high quality post deserves much more attention than a LQ post? So with this queue I want to encourage users to put effort into their posts.

Comment: @Rizier123 if the website had less crap on it, yes, I'd be with you, honestly. But right now, we're being overrun by a tsunami of bad stuff. Moving efforts away from it won't be productive I think

Comment: How long do things stay in the queue?

Comment: @NathanOliver As the amount you can send into this queue also the time  they stay in can be discussed or adjusted over time. Because it's hard to tell how many users find and send posts into the queue and how many people review this queue.

Comment: I would recommend posting a new request, *if* - and *only* if - you can figure out how to identify high-quality posts without relying on votes. Play around with [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) a bit maybe...

Comment: @Shog9 Okay. I will give it some time and look if I have any other ideas until I think it is ready for a new post :)

Answer (score 7):

While this could be interesting, I really don't see the point.

It seems like a review queue of this sort would serve to either:

- Get already popular posts more undue attention/votes
- Or it could dissolve into a free for all where everyone would try to dump their favorite question/answer into it.

Either way it seems like a good deal of work for little benefit.

Ask yourself "What problem does this solve?" If the only problem being solved is getting more upvotes/views, then why do we need a review queue for that?

I'm also concerned that this sort of reviewing could end up skewing the meaning of votes. The current tooltip reads: "This post shows research effort; it is useful and clear" and that's what an upvote should mean, it shouldn't become an "Oh, this post spent a good long time in the High Quality Review and got more attention than it should have."
Think of it like the Meta effect or the Hot Questions sidebar...

Comment: *"What problem does this solve?"* With this we would have not only a review for low quality, but also for good quality, so that we can get **more votes in both directions** to identify the quality of a post; *Get already popular posts more undue attention/votes* That's exactly it, it should bring **attention unknown and hidden good posts**, which don't have views/votes, but maybe deserve it. Or the post can be very good used as duplicate. Also the **meaning of votes shouldn't get changed at all**; You should vote as the tooptips on up/down vote says it.

Comment: FYI: updated my question, so if you want to edit/change your answer according to that